# Escaping slash in HTTP request

Tags: java, http, url, tomcat, jetty

I perform a http **DELETE** request from Javascript to a Java web app. The web app uses **Jersey** to dispatch urls. Tricky thing is, I'm using a path parameter that contains a forward-slash (e.g. **"XX/6666"**). When I run in **Jetty** (maven plugin) it works fine, but when I run on my production server (**Tomcat**) it does not, i.e. I get a **404**.

The forward slash is escaped using %2F so my request URL looks something like

DELETE `http://.../4776/shipmentOrders/XX%2F6666`

Is this allowed in the http specs, and is it possible Jetty and Tomcat interpret these differently?

Comment: Can you show the request code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tomcat (in versions 5, 6 and 7 I believe) purposefully prevents the usage of %2f in the path to prevent directory traversal attacks.  You can allegedly turn this protection OFF by setting org.apache.tomcat.util.buf. UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true.  I've not personally tested this, but see others on the net claiming it resolved this for them.  Note, however, that web servers in front of Tomcat may also intercept and rewrite the URL, automatically decoding %2f to the forward slash.

Reference: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

Comment: I've since worked around this issue, so I will not verify this, but I will accept your answer since it is very complete.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to both: it is allowed, but it is possible that some servers reject the request for security reasons.